# Deleting memory from function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm having trouble freeing my memory I'm using and a little confused how I would go about doing it.  When I do it with the code below i get an error "Heap Corruption Detected... CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".  I also debugged to make sure there is a memory leak using the Crtdb and there is a leak on that variable.  Just am confused how to free it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
void adjustVar(char*& pointer, size_t i) {
   pointer = new char[i];
}

int main(void) {
   const char* org = "HELLOWORLD";
   char* p = nullptr;
   size_t size = strlen(org);
   adjustVar(p, size);
   memset(p, 0, size+1);
   strncpy(p, org, size);
   cout << p << endl;
   delete[] p;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code should work, but normally, you would use something that manages the memory, not raw pointers.

Comment: @awesomeyi thanks i just fixed that

Comment: @chris it does work, im just trying to make sure im not having a memory leak is all. so im trying to use a delete since i used a new.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I added the headers and several more lines of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the updated code, you actually do overflow the buffer, causing heap corruption:

```
size_t size = strlen(org);
adjustVar(p, size);
memset(p, 0, size+1);    // overflow by 1 byte
```

Also, It is poor style to use `memset` and `strncpy` like that; replace with:

```
size_t size = strlen(org);
adjustVar(p, size + 1);
strcpy(p, org);
```

`strncpy` has very few valid uses, because it does not terminate its buffer in some cases; either `strcpy` or `memcpy` should be preferred, depending on what you want.

Comment: Ok that did it, do you think you could explain more in depth what happened? or if you have maybe a reference online somewhere i could read more about it?

Comment: When you allocate memory with `new`, the compiler puts bookkeeping information nearby in memory.  So going outside your allocated area means you could overwrite this.  In this case it probably wouldn't touch anything because that info would be before your buffer rather than after it. However if you had done another memory allocation after this one, then overflowing this buffer could trash the details of that other memory allocation.  Your error message seems to be detecting that you went outside the bounds of your allocation, whether or not it trashed something else this particular time.

Comment: It should go without saying that you should not write outside the bounds of memory you have allocated :)

Answer (score 1):

It runs fine here:  http://ideone.com/Ap2DjG

As an answer though, don't use pointers. If you find yourself using char* use `std::string` instead. And if you absolutely have to use pointers then consider wrapping them in `boost` or `c++11` smart pointers.